# using OpenNI2 with persee in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, openni

I am trying to compile a sample Persee example SimpleViewer. However. I get many errors in OpenNI.h, regarding undefined references to functions.

Why is this happening?

Also can someone mention in detail what all files/paths/libraries are to be linked from where and how to properly integrate openNI with codeblocks?